# How to display profile picture from database in dompdf laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I want to display profile picture from database in my result of generate PDF by dompdf, but the result is `Image not found or type unknown`

My controller

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{ 
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $user = array(
         "photo_url" =>  User::select("PHOTO_URL")->where("id", $id)->get()
        )
  $data["user"] = $user;

  $pdf = PDF::loadView('generatePDF', $data);
  return $pdf->stream('generatePDF.pdf');
```

My view

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/imgprofile') . '/' . $user['photo_url'][0]['PHOTO_URL'] }}" width="220" height="220" alt="Profile Picture" />
```

Comment: I didn't see how you are passing the $user to the view, shouldn't you use $data['user']['photo_url'][0]? And this asset on this string doesn't make sense to me, try to use on your variable instead

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
User::select("PHOTO_URL")->where("id", $id)->get()
```

Replace with:

```
User::find($id, ['PHOTO_URL'];
```

In your view:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/imgprofile') . '/' . $user->PHOTO_URL }}" width="220" height="220" alt="Profile Picture" />
```